# How can I specify TestNG tests to run in Jenkins build?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I am using Java, Selenium, Maven, and TestNG to execute automated tests. I am using Jenkins to clone the GitHub repo and start the tests when a build is started. Currently I have tests for several applications in one project. My testng.xml file looks similar to below, "appOne" being one application and "appTwo" being another application, both running the "production" grouped tests.

```
<test name="appOne">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name = "production" />
        </run>
    </groups>
</test>

<test name="appTwo">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name = "production" />
        </run>
    </groups>
</test>
```

Is there a way that I can pass these parameters through Jenkins so I can choose which apps to run with each Jenkins build. This scenario might also happen if I want to run all tests in the group "test." Currently, I make the change in the testng.xml file and then commit my change to GitHub.

Or would it be better to have a separate project for each application, therefore a different build for each app using separate testng.xml files?

Comment: You dont need seperate project  but you can do is separate each app into its own xml file and you parametrize it in the xml. If you need more help let me know.

Comment: @mbn217 I definitely could do that, but not sure what it would gain me. My end goal is for a user to be able to build and kick off the tests with their desired parameters from the Jenkins UI. The process of editing the xml and commiting and pushing to the GitHub repo allows a lot of room for error.

Comment: Yes exactly, by parametrizing the Pom , when you run the mvn command you will pass the path of your xml and you can parameterize that too in jenkins and use choise paramter to pass app1 or app 2 from your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mbn217 gave me the answer in the comments. I removed all groups from my testng.xml file. I then split my testng.xml file per application (one file per application). In my pom.xml, my surefire plugin looks like this...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${testngTarget}</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
        <groups>${groupTarget}</groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In Jenkins, I added that it was a parameterized build and added the names and default values of the parameters. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Or would it be better to have a separate project for each application, therefore a different build for each app using separate testng.xml files?

If this is a two different apps and there is no reasonable reason, would be better to separate job for each app in jenkins.